# cannot access ftp site via IE, Chrome or Firefox

Tags: networking, ftp, filezilla

I have the following FTP details as an example:

**Server:** 10.10.100.10

**User:** dreamer

**Password:** 12345

When I used FileZilla I can access the FTP site with the above credentials.

When I use windows explorer, I put this in the address bar **`ftp://10.10.100.10`**, I get a pop-up asking for credentials, which I enter and this works.

However, when I use IE, firefox or Chrome, I cannot get in.

I use this in the address bar: **`ftp://dreamer:12345@10.10.100.10`**

Please note, this is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Filezilla right click on the file you want to access.

Select 'Copy URL(s) to clipboard' and paste that into your browser a popup window should appear asking for logins.

That works for me.

Comment: I get the following url from filezilla **'ftp://dreamer@10.10.100.10'** there is no pop-up for password, it just says access denied.

Comment: Perhaps there are some sort of permissions that are blocking you accessing it in a browser, speak to your host about that it might be some restrictions you have enabled on your account. Another thing, its probably unlikely that this is the cause but also check if your java script enabled on those browsers.